# Freeform Pro Select field issues with Channel Population

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm having an issue with Freeform Pro's select field. Currently it is filling in from a channel using the title of the channels, however it grabs all channel entries, irregardless of the channel entries' status.

I need to be able to get only "Open" entries.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Renders this otherwise awesome feature useless.